# IDE shows no errors in Java compilation unit even though method is unresolved

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, reflection

I was browsing a piece of code(`android.app.Activity.java`) and I found a method call,

```
   public void invalidateOptionsMenu(){
    if (mWindow.hasFeature(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL) &&
                (mActionBar == null || !mActionBar.invalidateOptionsMenu())) {
            mWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(Window.FEATURE_OPTIONS_PANEL);
        }
    }
```

Now, this is not a question that pertains specifically to Android but a question related to Java and the IDE.
I am using Android Studio and it shows this method call in red with message, "**Cannot resolve method invalidateOptionsMenu()**" but overall there is no error in parsing and compilation of Activity.java.

Not only this method but there are others that are unresolved. I checked mActionBar's type and it is ActionBar. I went to `ActionBar.invalidateOptionsMenu()` and method exists.

First, why is the compilation unit being able to be parsed and then compiled even though there are unresolved method calls.
Second, even though the method exists(and shouldn't show unresolved), How should this behavior of IDE be interpreted as?

Comment: Sounds like there's a jar (or directory) in your real classpath that isn't being scanned by IntelliJ for the purposes of proactive notifications. So check that the project settings include all the jars and directories the real classpath includes.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder . It is Android Studio and the Android APIs come default as the standard ones with the Java ones. So, they are all included in the classpath. Also, some methods are unresolved and the rest are not. This is suspicious to me. These all methods and classes constitute the core API of Android SDK.

Comment: Well, which is it, Android Studio or IntelliJ? You said *"I am using Intellij and..."* In any case, it's worth double-checking the paths. There are basically two explanations: 1. The project doesn't include things the classpath does, and so the IDE can't find them; 2. The IDE is broken. IntelliJ is one of the most widely-used and respectied Java IDEs in the world, so on a "select isn't broken" basis, I would assume 1 over 2.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay, I shall double check on the class-path and it is not broken but I think behavior should be interpreted as something I don;t know about.

Comment: I don't see why. If the code compiles, but the IDE says there's an error (as opposed to a warning, or a style note), that just means either the IDE is working with incorrect information or has a bug. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA there is an option to invalidate cache and restart:

> File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate and Restart

If you are using maven you should reimport your dependencies too:

> Open the "Maven Projects" tab/window > Reimport All Maven Projects